# Помогите составить программу для подсчета максимального количества подряд идущих отрицательных элементов

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, коллекции

```
a = []
b = 0
c = 0
d = 30
for i in range(0, d):
    a.append(int(input()))
    if a[i] < 0:
        b = b + 1
    if a[i + 1] >= 0:
        if b > c:
            c = b
            b = 0
print(c)
```

Надо описать на Питоне алгоритм подсчета максимального количества подряд идущих отрицательных элементов в целочисленном массиве длины 30.

Я написал такую программу выше, но выдает ошибку в строке `if a[i + 1] >= 0:`
не понимаю почему , ведь если вместо плюса поставить минус то все работает

Comment: Если в массив добавлен элемент a[i] - ведь при этом следующего пока ещё нет, не так ли? А с -1  -  это особенности индексации в Python

Comment: а как мне тогда сравнить следующий элемент с нулем?

Comment: проверяйте текущий

Comment: ОК. Сначала полностью введите массив, потом обрабатывайте.

Comment: в задании написано, что программа должна работать для любого списка, я понял свою ошибку, спасибо большое за помощь

Answer (score 5):

```
import itertools

my_list = [7, 6, -3, -3, -8, 2, -5, 4, -8, -2, -6, -1]

is_negative = [True if num < 0 else False for num in my_list]
groups = itertools.groupby(is_negative)
occurrences_of_negatives = [len(list(g)) for k, g in groups if k]

result = max(occurrences_of_negatives)
```

---

Обяснение:

Сначала создаем новый список `is_negative`, чтобы получить *только 2 категории*:

- `True` для *отрицательных* чисел,
- `False` для всех других.

В нашем случае получим из списка `my_list`:

> ```
> [  7,     6,   -3,   -3,   -8,     2,   -5,     4,   -8,   -2,   -6,   -1 ]
> ```

такой список `is_negative`:

> ```
> [False, False, True, True, True, False, True, False, True, True, True, True]
> ```

Затем функцией `itertools.groupby()` получим из него *группы подряд идучшицх значений* - что то как словарь, хотя это не словарь - в нашем случае

> ```
> {False: [False, False],
>  True:  [True, True, True],
>  False: [False],
>  True:  [True],
>  False: [False],
>  True:  [True, True, True, True]}
> ```

Из него построим список *только для ключей `True`*, причем нас интересуют только *длины* подходящих списков. В нашем случае будет список `occurrences_of_negatives` таким:

> ```
> [3, 1, 4]
> ```

И это почти всё - результатом будет максимальное значение в этом сиписке.

Comment: Можно проще: `is_negative = [num < 0 for num in my_list]`

Answer (score 2):

Исправленный алгоритм из вопроса:

```
items = []
number = 0
max_number = 0
max_arr_len = 5

for i in range(max_arr_len):
    x = int(input())

    items.append(x)

    if x < 0:
        number += 1
        if number > max_number:
            max_number = number
    else:
        number = 0

print(max_number)
```

---

Тот же алгоритм, но для обработки всего списка:

```
my_list = [7, 6, -3, -3, -8, 2, -5, 4, -8, -2, -6, -1]

number = 0
max_number = 0

for x in my_list:
    if x < 0:
        number += 1
        if number > max_number:
            max_number = number
    else:
        number = 0

print(max_number)  # 4
```